# ASP.NET Razor: Dynamically wrapping ever 6 elements in bootstrap rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Currently in my viewmodel, I have a collection of varying size and I would like to create a row out of every 6 elements I iterate though (because the html im producing has `col-lg-2` so this should form an equally spaced row of elements. I am struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong. The rendered HTML has the row elements in the wrong areas (sometimes 7 per row). Please see code below- all help is appreciated

```
@{int numItemsDisplayed = 0}

@foreach (var item in Model.SomeCollection)
{
    if (numItemsDisplayed == 0 || numItemsDisplayed % 6 == 0)
    {
        @:<div class="row">
    }
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="gridBox" data-id="@item.id">
            <div class="logo">
                <span class="lightText">@item.Name</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    if (numItemsDisplayed % 6 == 0 && numItemsDisplayed != 0)
    {
        @:</div>
    }
    numItemsDisplayed++;
}
```

another challenge I am encountering with this is ensuring that the last row is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, you are not properly closing the outer divs. Instead of rendering the closing div, you are opening another div (for row). So basically generating nested divs for row. (check view source of the generated html)

The below code will render 6 col-lg-2 divs inside each row div.

```
@{
    var numberOfColsNeeded = 6;
    var totalCounter = Model.SomeCollection.Count();
    var itemCounter = 1;
}

@foreach (var item in Model.SomeCollection)
{
    if (itemCounter % numberOfColsNeeded == 1)
    {
        @:<div class="row" >
    }
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="gridBox" data-id="@item.Id">
            <div class="logo">
                <span class="lightText">@item.Name</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    if ((itemCounter % numberOfColsNeeded == 0) || ((itemCounter) == totalCounter))
    {
        @:</div>
    }
    itemCounter++;
}
```